# Build unsuccessful : Error with Android project in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I just create a small Xamarin.Forms sample application. When i build my Android project i get some errors.
I just googled errors and find some solutions. But nothing works fine.
Last day i had reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin Studio.
So probably xamarin will be updated in all.

Here I just list my errors and suggested solutions.

---

***Error 1 :***

*Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r10.zip and extract it to the ...~\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\content directory.*

***Suggested solution :***
*The file is downloaded successfully and replaced as per the error message.*

---

***Error 2 :***
_Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file ...~\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.
Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Java library file ...~\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\libs/internal_impl-21.0.3.jar doesn't exist._

***Suggested solution :***
*Android Support Library is deleted and reinstalled.*

---

***Error 3 :***
*Reason:  ...~\Local\Xamarin\zips\1FD832DCC1792D8ACA07FAC3259FC5A9.zip is not a valid zip file.*

***Suggested solution :***
*I didn't find any solutions for this error.*

---

These solutions are still useless. and not working in my case.

---

I'm using :

- **Xamarin   4.0.0.1689 (f860fe4)**
- **Xamarin.Android   6.0.0.34 (3efa14c)**
- **Xamarin.iOS   9.2.1.51 (3c0ec35)**

---

Here is the detailed report :

**=== Xamarin Studio ===**

Version 5.10 (build 871)
Installation UUID: c5309e12-1ab1-494c-9296-033a0a5c3f24
Runtime:
    Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (MS-Windows theme)
    GTK# 2.12.30

**=== Xamarin.Android ===**

Version: 6.0.0
Android SDK: D:\Android\android-sdk
    Supported Android versions:
        2.3    (API level 10)
        4.0.3  (API level 15)
        4.1    (API level 16)
        4.2    (API level 17)
        4.3    (API level 18)
        4.4    (API level 19)
        4.4.87 (API level 20)
        5.0    (API level 21)
        5.1    (API level 22)
        6.0    (API level 23)

SDK Tools Version: 24.4

SDK Platform Tools Version: 23.0.1

SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.1

Java SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

**=== Xamarin Android Player ===**

Version: 0.6.5
Location: C:\Program Files\Xamarin Android Player\DeviceManager.exe

**=== Build Information ===**

Release ID: 510000871
Git revision: 4e9c5abb5ffdae12ba02ac49da83f8b2011dbb88
Build date: 2015-11-12 07:16:34-05
Xamarin addins: 55007ed0e56436f385d8e26394a45be563abc7e8
Build lane: monodevelop-windows-cycle6

**=== Operating System ===**

Windows 6.3.9600.0 (64-bit)

***Any ideas or suggestions to come out of this errors ?***

Comment: I have written a few workarounds in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/f6291eacd4da5f6aa4cd

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT:** This information is now included in our documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/resolving-library-installation-errors/

## Xamarin.Android Support Library NuGet m2repository fixes

#### 1. Investigation

You may run into issues with downloading the `m2repository` when referencing a NuGet package of the Android Support Libraries / Google Play Services.

**Example error:**

`Download failed. Please download
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r25.zip
and put it to the
C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\{SUPPORT LIBRARY NAME}\{VERSION NUMBER}
directory."`

**Mac Directory:** `/Users/[Username]/.local/share/Xamarin/`

**Windows Directory:** `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\`

#### 2. Folder Contents

This example will be using Windows paths. This can be applied to either OS.

- Given the following:  `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\`
- A folder for each of the respective Android Support Libraries / Google Play Services will be shown.

[image]

- Each library should have a collection of versions:

[image]

**Note:** In this example I'm showing all of the versions of `Android.Support.v4`

- We will then investigate the respective version we're interested in. We should see two folders inside, `content` and `embedded`:

[image]

1. `content` - Contains the `m2repository`
2. `embedded` - Contains the respective `.aar` contents

#### 3. Automatic Fix

- Delete the versioned library folder that is giving you errors:

**Mac Directory:** `/Users/[Username]/.local/share/Xamarin/{SUPPORT LIBRARY NAME}/{VERSION NUMBER}`

**Windows Directory:** `C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\{SUPPORT LIBRARY NAME}\{VERSION NUMBER}`

- Rebuild your project (Which will kickoff a Build Task to re-download the library).

#### 4. Manual Fix

There are two steps to manually fixing this error.

1. Adding the `m2repository` folder to the `/content` folder.
2. Adding the respective Android Support Library / Google Play Services `.aar` contents to the `/embedded` folder.

1. Adding the m2repository to the /content folder

Download the respective `m2repository` from google.

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r25.zip

**Note:** This version number will vary based on your error message.

- Extract that .zip to any directory. There should now be a `android_m2repository_r25` folder.
- Inside the `android_m2repository_r25` folder, we have a `m2repository` folder.
- Place the `m2repository` into the `{VERSION NUMBER}/content` folder

[image]

2. Adding the .aar contents to the /embedded folder

- Inside the `m2repository` folder, there is an .aar for the support library to be resolved. It can be found in the `com\android\support` directory:

**Example:**

`m2repository\com\android\support`

- There should be a `support-v4\{VERSION NUMBER}` which will contain the `.aar` file.
- Extract the `.aar` and put the contents into the `embedded` folder.

**Example:**

- `m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\23.1.1\support-v4-23.1.1` will contain items such as a `aapt`, `aidl`, `assets`, `libs`, `res`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, `annotations.zip`, and `classes.jar`.
- Place all of the contents into the `{VERSION NUMBER}/embedded` folder.

#### 5. New Manual Fix

- Get the URL of the missing m2repository download
- Use a MD5 hash on the download URL
- Rename the file to {MD5HASH}.zip (Where MD5HASH is the hashed download URL)
- Place the new hashed .zip file in your Xamarin\zips directory

Comment: Genius! Number 5 is what worked for me, thank you very much. I've tried everything else.

Comment: Did the manul install but classes.jar is missing in the downloaded .zip file. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Delete all the zip files. Even if it asks you to download and replace, it will corrupt again. The quicker way is to just delete all the zip files and rebuild, it will automatically download and unzip as required.

The Android m2repository gets corrupted often on my machine.

With Android I also suggest, build against API 23 (6.0) and set you minimum level to 15 (unless you really need API 10). Make sure you don't use the "Latest SDK" selection, that has been known to cause issues in the past as well, select the highest API beneath that.

Answer (score 4):

Delete the zip at \Local\Xamarin\zips\1FD832DCC1792D8ACA07FAC3259FC5A9.zip

Clean and Rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I get that problem when tried to use xamarin forms 2.0

The problem usually comes when IDE (VS2015 for example) try to decompress that zip... VS hangs and you must force close it ... when you reopen the IDE you cannot compile anything with xamarin that use this version.

First of all you should download r23 no r10. Each one contains assemblies for each version api.

When you have it you should delete library folder on C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin for example Android.Support.v4

Create a path with the library name C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin{LibraryName}\23.0.1

Copy and unzip download r23 to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\22.2.10\content

Go to m2repository\com\android\support and under libraryname\version you will get a file with extension ".aar" this is a zip file rename to .rar and unzip it to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin{LibraryName}\23.0.1\embedded

By the way a copy of downloaded r23.zip must be leaved on:

C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin{library name}\23.0.1\

When you have done this you are able to compile again

Answer (score 2):

Spent a whole night struggling to get this working, turned out i had forcefully shut down VS during an initial build thinking it got stuck not knowing it was actually downloading a > 200MB file to my C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips folder.

Deleting the corrupt zip file and being patient enough to rerun a rebuild definitely fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

In Simple Words

-> After ***handling and clearing all the Errors*** in your Xml documents

-> click on the ***hammer icon*** to build and make project Or Press ***Ctrl+F9***

[image: This Hammer Icon Make Project]