# Xamarin.Forms: Android project Build Error - Missing Files inside AppData\Local\Xamarin Folders

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono

I'm trying the Xamarin.Forms.
I created a Solution named "App2". The Visual Studio automatically created the following projects:

- App2 (Portable)
- App2.Droid
- App2.iOS

When I try to compile the Android Project (App2.Droid), I get the following errors:

> Download failed. Please download
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip
>   and put it to the
>   C:\Users\pedro.costa\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3
>   directory.    App2.Droid           Reason: One or more errors.    App2.Droid
>   Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in
>   SDK installer. Java library file
>   C:\Users\pedro.costa\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar
>   doesn't exist.    App2.Droid           Download failed. Please download
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip
>   and put it to the
>   C:\Users\pedro.costa\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3
>   directory.    App2.Droid           Reason: One or more errors.    App2.Droid
>   Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in
>   SDK installer. Android resource directory
>   C:\Users\pedro.costa\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\embedded./
>   doesn't exist.    App2.Droid

I've already tried to:

- Download the android_m2repository_r22.zip file and put it on the C:\Users\pedro.costa\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3 folder
- Download the file and extract it to the folder
- Delete the C:\Users\pedro.costa\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3 folder and recompile project
- Delete the C:\Users\pedro.costa\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips folder and recompile the project.
- Update the Xamarin.Android.Support.* nuget packages, but when I try it, I also get those build errors.

I've done a lot of research and it seems that the Android.Support.* folders should have files inside it, and that those files should be downloaded when the android solution is built, but it is not happening for me.

Comment: The only thing that solved it for me was this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36215224/914037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw in other answers to this problem, that by just deleting all the content from the Android.Support.Design folder, Visual Studio would download it again once the project was rebuild.

The problem in my case, was a proxy issue. When I set my environment to access the internet without the proxy, Visual Studio download the necessary files and folders on the rebuild.

Answer (score 4):

Try this work around :

- Navigate to `C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips` folder.
- Remove all zip files.
- Remove `/bin` and `/obj`from your project.
- Clean and build your project.

It may take a while to build and debug  project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try that, but my zips folder don't have any files.

Comment: Tryied this solution, but no success. I got the same errors. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

1.download 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip

2.rename to 2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip

3.copy to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zip

4.rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Don't extract the zip to `\23.0.1.3`folder or just put it there, that won't work don't mind the error message.
You must put the zip in the `\zip` folder, after you delete the already existing zip, you may need to rename the zip you downloaded to something like: `2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip`

But if you don't want to manually download the support repository you can just delete everything in the `%USER%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\` folder and rebuild and wait.

Answer (score 0):

there is a zips name folder over this address `C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips` 
first u have to check it the file is in extract condition there we can see an error it is an currupt format then u can replace those two files 
1)2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip replace by [this](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip) link rename with 2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41

2)96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0.zip replace by [this](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip) link rename with 96659D653BDE0FAEDB818170891F2BB0

then rebuild the project