# Build errors in blank Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-support-library, xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin for VS and I get 36 errors, this is the first one:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\Cayl\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\embedded./ doesn't exist.  forms.Droid

I gather it's because XF don't support the current Android Support Library I have (23.1.1), how do I fix this step by step, do I uninstall Android Support Library and get 23.0.1 from internet somewhere or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms: Android project Build Error - Missing Files inside AppData\Local\Xamarin Folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418129/xamarin-forms-android-project-build-error-missing-files-inside-appdata-local)

Comment: Those errors are due to the failure to automatically download the zip files from Google the first time (after that they are cached for project reuse). If you have network access ` https://dl-ssl.google.com/....`, then cleaning and rebuilding the project "should" work, sometimes exiting Visual Studio (or Xamarin Studio on OS-X) and then rebuilding will start the downloads again. Otherwise the error message show the download link for the zip file(s) needed and the directory that you need to manually place them in.

Comment: @SushiHangover What first time? you mean first time running the msi installer, I use the full one (350mb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are due to the failure to automatically download the zip files from Google the first time (after that they are cached for project reuse).

If you have network access to `dl-ssl.google.com`, then cleaning and rebuilding the project "should" work. Sometimes exiting and restarting Visual Studio (or Xamarin Studio on OS-X) and then rebuilding will start the downloads again properly.

Otherwise the error message shows the download link for the zip file(s) needed and the directory that you need to manually place them in:

#### Example Error Message:

> Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip and put it to the C:\Users\YOURUSERID\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3 directory.

Once they are downloaded, they will be available for all future solution/projects.

Comment: What is this android_m2repository_r22? frankly I'm tired of downloading things, I have everything to run regular Xamarin.Android apps already. Can't I just download Android Support Library 23.0.1 from somewhere and get over it?

Comment: @JonneyShih These Google Android Support zips are NOT included from Microsoft/Xamarin. They are downloaded as needed from Google and cached for reuse from that point on.

Comment: @JonneyShih Can you download them? Yes, the download link(s) are provided in the error message and the location that you need to save them to is also in that message.

Comment: I downloaded the package but I don't know where to unzip, I'm still getting errors. @SushiHangover

Comment: @JonneyShih You do **not** have to unzip it. Just place it in the directory that is specified in the original build error message, It will be something like: C:\Users\YOURUSERID\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3 but with your Windows' user name

Comment: It's working, everything is good now, I just don't understand why I have to copy the same files to 5 different locations @SushiHangover

Comment: I glad to hear you have it working now. Happy programming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have a corrupt download. Please try deleting the zips folder, and any Android.Support.* folders from inside C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin.

Then, delete the bin/ and obj/ folders from your solution's project folders, restart Visual Studio, and rebuild.