# Xamarin is looking for android sdks in the wrong location & giving build errors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm having a persistent build issue that I can't resolve, I've tried xamarin support forums.

When I build my project, it can't find any of my Xamarin.Android.Support.* packages.

I have all of my Xamarin.Android.Support.* libraries included as nuget packages. They appear correct in my packages.config and csproj file, and the references folder in my project shows they are recognized.

The issue appears to be that the build is looking for these packages in a completely different folder, which is my local user AppData folder. I have no clue why it is looking there, but I think this is the issue.

I'm lost and can't figure out why it is looking here.

Error details:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar doesn't exist.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar doesn't exist.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\./ doesn't exist.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable' available in SDK installer. Java library file C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar doesn't exist.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Reason: C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\2A3A8A6D6826EF6CC653030E7D695C41.zip is not a valid zip file   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content directory.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content directory.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\content directory.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\content directory.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content directory.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content directory.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\content directory.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\content directory.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\content directory.  CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\content directory.   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\content directory.   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content directory.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content directory.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\content directory.    CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\content directory.   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\content directory.   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content directory.   CiiCommon.Droid         
Error       Unzipping failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r29.zip and extract it to the C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\content directory.   CiiCommon.Droid
```

edit: it is not a duplicate of [Build unsuccessful : Error with Android project in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869051/build-unsuccessful-error-with-android-project-in-xamarin-forms) as this issue was related to corrupted zip files.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your machine? I'm almost certain I had this happen to me once and I don't think I ever did find a solution or cause. I think restarting my machine fixed it but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build unsuccessful : Error with Android project in Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869051/build-unsuccessful-error-with-android-project-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes Visual Studio will timeout while downloading the appropriate libraries it requires, and it'll give build issues because certain packages appear to be installed, but the files have been corrupted.

What I'd suggest doing is closing Visual Studio, deleting all the files from C:\Users\jwierzba.ASSOCIATIONVOIC\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips, restarting Visual Studio, and rebuilding the project. This will force Visual Studio to download those libraries again from scratch.

You can fix the 260 character limit by right-clicking on your specific project in Solution Explorer, selecting "Properties", navigating to the "Build" tab, and changing the Output path.

Comment: I've tried this and it then gave me a "path too long" error. Could you please tell me what is the significance of this app data folder? Why is it placing files in there? Can the location be changed?

Comment: The app data folder is where VS stores project-related files and builds your project.

Comment: I believe the Xamarin files stored here exceed the 260 char path limit on Windows. Would you tell me please what exactl setting you are referring to so I can place it closer to the root?

Comment: Sorry, didn't intend for the last comment to post. Am editting my answer accordingly

Comment: Karl, if I delete the zip files, it will just re-generate them and try again to unzip them and again exceed 260 chars. Also, the setting you suggested isnt correct. The `Project Properties -> Build -> Output path` is already set to `bin\Debug` which is a folder relative to my visual studio solution folder. This isn't the setting that is pointing to `...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\` , do you know where I can change the drop location of these zip files?

Comment: Hi James. I'm looking into it a bit more. Will come back to you as soon as I find something that makes sense as a work-around.

Comment: Thank you Karl I appreciate all the help thus far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129414/discussion-between-karl-buys-and-james-wierzba).