# failed to download android m2repository_r32.zip

Tags: android, xamarin

When i build my xamarin android app i get this above error failed to download android m2repository_r32.zip. Another error is no definition for the name theme in the mainactivity class. when i build it creates empty folders on c/users/username/appdata/xamarin

```
xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable
xamarin.android.support.v4
xamarin.android.support.v7.appCompat
xamarin.android.support.vector.drawable.
```

I downloaded the m2repository and installed it manually but that did not work also i dont know what to do. I installed android support library v7 appCompat

Comment: The last time I had this problem was due to the file path size limit on Windows. I think it's only 256 characters and while the archive was extracting, it suddenly failed and resulted in the error you're receiving. What version of Windows are you running and do you see any mentions to file paths in the logs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36215224/6146870

Comment: i am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when aborting the Android build while it is downloading the packages.

Right-click the Android project and select `Clean` then `Rebuild`.

If this does not fix the problem:

1. Close Visual Studio / Xamarin Studio
2. Open the folder where your Android project lies and delete the `obj` and `bin` folder
3. Open the folder where your `.sln` file and `packages` folder lies and delete the `packages` folder
4. Go to the `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\` folder
   (Windows) or `~/.nuget/packages` folder (Mac) and delete all
   **Xamarin.Android.*** folders
5. Go to the `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Xamarin` folder (Windows) or
   `~/.local/share/NuGet/Cache` folder (Mac) and delete all
   **Xamarin.Android.*** folders and the **zips** folder
6. Reopen Visual Studio / Xamarin Studio, right-click your Solution and select `Rebuild Solution`
7. Wait until it has finished and do not cancel the package restore or
   build

For more information about this problem, check http://smstuebe.de/2016/10/29/fix-android-app-compat/

Comment: Hi Robin i did all these steps but i still get the same error

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Download failed. Please download https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r32.zip and put it to the C:\Users\nphiliso\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.4.0.0 directory. ToDoList